# WISE API integration

Tags: node.js, wise

Im a Software Engineer and Im integrating `WISE API` to my node.js app.

In **Sandbox environment**, I can successfully transfer the payment to other recipent.

But, Im getting an error on **Live Environment**. on endpoint of **/v1/transfer**

Erorr:

```
{
 errors: [
{
  code: 'error.quote.accept.approvalRequired',
  message: 'Quote cannot be accepted with this request due to missing approval',
  arguments: []
}
```

]
}

Can anyone please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: I ran into the same problem 
How did you solve it?

Comment: I send the email to Wise and they said, In there Database, they have a field set to true which is for approval required. After some discussion they resolved my issue.